# How to write an import script?

Tags: scripting, import

I have searched and read scripting tutorials, but without any previous scripting experience it has presently proved to be difficult to write an import script.

I want to make a Blender import script for an ascii file format (.mdb). Could anyone be so kind as to show me where to begin?

[Example file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/frwp9995q4w7b3c/UKMorris.zip)

Comment: Hello and welcome, this site is more geared towards helping you do it, rather than do it for you. For the later there's a [job section](https://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?51-Jobs) over at Blender artists forum, its better to post there

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and tip. I understand this and I want to be able to do it myself as stated in the question. - To be more precise> I would need to know what parts thats is strictly needed to make an import script for this format?

Comment: @T-Rex That's a rather broad and far-reaching question. There are no doubt many ways to implement such a script, and answers about this specific format wouldn't likely be useful to outsiders coming in from search engines etc. The Q&A format of this site lends itself better to answering small specific questions which can apply to many different problems. I suggest giving it a shot yourself, then if and when you encounter a problem, come back and ask about that problem.

Comment: That said, I think it would be fine as a general question. I've taken the liberty of editing your question with that end in mind; if you don't agree with my edits please feel free to [roll them back](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing)

Comment: OK, I didnt now my question was so complicated or far-reaching, so nice of you to help narrow it down.

Comment: The template suggested in the answer below is _"the bare minimum for an import script to run"_   Edit  any occurrences of `.txt` to `.mdb`. Run,  and if it prints file to the system console you are one step closer to your goal of writing the script yourself.   Then [a simple google search](https://www.google.com?q=python+read+ascii+mdb+file) will reveal a wealth of information.

Answer (score 4):

You may use the **Operator File Import** template which is provided by default.

Open the Text Editor > Templates > Python

[image]

I hope, this template would give you good enough starting point and customize it as you go along with your specific needs and requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the template tip. I specified the question a bit better now as it was too wide in scope.- Basically I need to know the bare minimum for an import script to run.