# Import function for custom file type - add button to import submenu

Tags: scripting, customization, file-browser

I wrote a Python script that is parsing a file of type that Blender does not support.

Now I want to add a new button to *File -> Import*.
After clicking on the button the file selector window needs to pop up, in a same way as if you would be importing .obj models, but I cannot figure out the code.

I checked various doc pages that seems to be relevant to Blender UI/menus but I'm unable to find anything relevant.

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Window.html

Comment: Have a look into *Text Editor > Templates > Python > Operator File Import*. Note that when you run the script, the *menu_func_import* function also adds to operator to the *File > Import* menu. Does this meet your requirements?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97230/how-to-write-an-import-script/97232#97232 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106983/how-do-i-add-a-new-file-type-to-the-import-menu https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30678/bpy-file-browser-get-selected-file-names/30681#30681